# My php code outputs random semi colons

Tags: php, html, mysql

My PHP and HTML code is used to get data from a MySQL database and display it in a table run through a while loop, however there are random semicolons being output before the table tag starts and the h3 tag ends (seen through inspect element in browser). The number of semicolons outputted matches the number of rows from the SQL query.

```
echo "<form action='predictions.php' method='POST'>";
        echo "<h3>" . $date[0] . "</h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
            <col width='100'>
            <col width='50'>
            <col width='50'>
            <col width='100'>
            <col width='70'>
            <col width='100'>
            <th>Home <br> Team</th>
            <th>Home <br> Score</th>
            <th>Away <br> Score</th>
            <th>Away <br> Team</th>
            <th>Match <br> Time </th>
            <th>First <br> Scorer </th>
            </tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($match) and $matchid = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlmatchid)){
            if ($date[0] != $row[3]) {
                    echo "</table>";
                    echo "<hr>";
                    $date[0] = $row[3];
                    echo "<h3>".$date[0]."</h3>
                    <table>
            <tr>
            <col width='100'>
            <col width='50'>
            <col width='50'>
            <col width='100'>
            <col width='70'>
            <col width='100'>
            <th>Home <br> Team</th>
            <th>Home <br> Score</th>
            <th>Away <br> Score</th>
            <th>Away <br> Team</th>
            <th>Match <br> Time </th>
            <th>First <br> Scorer </th>
            </tr>";
                    }
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>" ?>
              <td> <input id='phs' type='text' name=<?php echo "phs".$matchid['MatchID'] ?> size='1' maxlength='1'> </td>
              <td> <input id='pas' type='text' name=<?php echo "pas".$matchid['MatchID'] ?> size='1' maxlength='1'> </td>
              <?php
              $smatchid = $matchid['MatchID']; //match id to find scorer
              echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>" ?>
              <td> <select id="scorer" name=<?php echo "scorer".$matchid['MatchID'] ?>>
                    <option>  </option>
                    <?php
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT PlayerName 
                                        FROM players, matches
                                        WHERE matches.MatchID = '$smatchid' AND (players.TeamID = matches.HTeamID OR players.TeamID = matches.ATeamID)");
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){

                echo "<option> $row[0] </option>";

            }
            ?>
            </select> </td>;
            <?php
              echo "</tr>";

        }
```

I don't understand why these semicolons are appearing and want to remove them.

Comment: How about giving us an HTML sample. Plus, you really should put some quotes around your inputs. `echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>" ?>` missing one (semi-colon) there.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I had a semi colon there but removed it when testing for some errors and forgot to put it back there. Thanks

Comment: @user3432693 You should really be escaping data used in the context of HTML with `htmlspecialchars()`, or you risk creating invalid HTML and potentially opening yourself up to XSS attacks.  You should also use prepared/parameterized queries.  Never concatenate data directly into a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semicolon is coming because you have written `</select> </td>;`. Semicolon after `</td>` generating it every time. Remove it from there.